# Problems with installing Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, partitioning, xubuntu

I just picked up a pretty old Dell PC from a company's yard sale. It was previously running Windows XP, but I wanted to install Xubuntu on there. So, I downloaded the 32-bit .iso file, burned it to a CD, and booted the machine off the CD. From there, I created a new partition table for my hard drive (I tried to create another partition, ended up deleting Windows... Oh well), and used these partitions:

```
/ ext4 10000 MB
/usr ext4 19999 MB
/home ext4 28999 MB
swap swap 999 MB
```

However, when I click Install Now, it just stays at "Please Wait..." with no progress (or so it seems). The last entry I see in the code window below says:

```
(root) CMD (  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Is it just being a slow, old computer? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How long did you wait in response to `Please wait...`?

Comment: @Paul Around an hour. Should I have waited longer? It didn't show any other signs of installation.

Comment: You could try booting into the live environment at the boot menu. If this fails you could be having hardware problems. Easy things to test are the memory and the hard drive.

Comment: That's the IDE on the CD-Rom, right? That's how I'm booting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Some old computers have issues booting recent Ubuntu images from IDE CD/DVD - it appears to be completely stuck for no reason. I have also seen similar issue when I was not able to install Windows 7 as well using DVD boot.

Easiest solution is to boot off USB stick. For Ubuntu, most convenient method to prepare such stick is [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) - it can take Ubuntu ISO and make USB stick out of it.

For Windows installation with buggy CD/DVD-ROM, easiest by far is to use [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).